# AndroidJSCore. RuntimeException

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-gradle

Cтолкнулись со следующей проблемой.

Когда программа приходит к:

```
JSContext = new JSContext ();
```

то выводит:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

В логах больше ничего нет. Все, что я делал раньше, это установить библиотеку Gradle, указанную в этой ссылке https://jitpack.io/#ericwlange/Android.

Я хотел начать работать с JS-скриптами на Android, но с самого начала уже непонятная ошибка. Заранее спасибо!!

Comment: У них в репозитории написано: **AndroidJSCore is DEPRECATED! All of this functionality and more is now maintained at its permanent home, [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore). Please migrate to this version going forward** . Думаю лучше начинать сразу с новой библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю. Скорее всего действительно дело в этой библиотеке